# Calling php query in javascript

Tags: php, function, jscript

So I have a jscript that creates a new text input and a drop-down select with each addition. That first one i have on the page is fine since the php function gets called on that page. The issue i have is my drop-down does not get populated by my query since i do not have the javascript function calling the php function. Im not sure how to add that in. 
Here is my Jscript function.

```
var counter = 1;
var limit = 45;
function addInput(divName){
    if (counter == limit)  {
        alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
    }
    else {
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
     newdiv.innerHTML = "Hop " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'><br>" +               "Type "+ (counter + 1) + " <br><select name='myInputs2[]' data-rel='chosen'><?php query() ?></select>" ;
    document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
    counter++;
   }
}
```

Here is my html. This drop-down (the first drop-down) Does get populated.

```
 <?php 
    include_once 'dropfunc2.php';
    connect (); ?>
  <script src="js/addInput.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
<form method="POST">
    <div id="dynamicInput">
        Hop 1<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]"><br>
        Type 1<br><select  name="myInputs2[]" data-rel="chosen"><?php query() ?></select>

    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Add Hop" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now I have tried doing what i have found on this site and making my jscript a .php page and adding the Header("content-type: application/javascript"); but then the function breaks completely and it does not add more inputs. I get a addInputs is not defined jscript error.

Comment: You need to use `ajax` to hit the server and request the data back. You're not going to be able to dynamically append data from a PHP function through your javascript as it stands.

Comment: Are you sure you mean jscript and not JavaScript?

Comment: I do mean JavaScipt. You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Put your PHP code to retrieve the data in a separate file and then call that script with AJAX. You can either send back formatted HTML or a JSON array to parse through and populate the  tags in JavaScript.

This will help you out if you're new to AJAX and don't want to use JQuery: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP

If you want to use JQuery, then check this out: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks so much. I do believe this is what I needed. I would give you an up vote but I cant.